# TabBarController: Dependency injection doesn't inject into subViewController

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, tabbarcontroller

I read a tutorial [denpendency injection](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-share-state-between-swift-view-controllers--cms-28474). And try to apply it into my app to pass the state into each subViewControllers of tabBarController in my case. But the modelController returns nil in subVC of tabBarController, I think there is something wrong in the passing of modelController instance, but I couldn't find it per several hours check...

Well, any help/ hint is highly appreciated.

First, I create an instance of ModelController in SceneDelegate since it is the rootViewController.

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        guard let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController as? TabBarController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Root View Controller")
        }

        rootViewController.modelController = ModelController()
    }
```

Then for test purpose, I inject it into one of subView of tabBarController(SongsViewController).

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var modelController: ModelController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else {
            return
        }
        
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            switch viewController {
            case let viewController as SongsViewController:
                viewController.modelController = modelController
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in SongsViewController, I test `modelController` in `viewWillAppear` but it returns nil.

```
class SongsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    // data source
    var songs = [Song]()
    
    // dependency injection from model controller
    var modelController: ModelController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.rowHeight = 66
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        guard modelController != nil else {
            fatalError("modelController is nil")
        }
        
        loadData()
    }
```

Comment: Try logging to find out in what order those assignments are happening.

Comment: Based on what you've said, I cannot reproduce any issue. Can you post a tiny example project that demonstrates the problem? perhaps you are doing something odd so that `viewWillAppear` happens sooner than you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, just wake up and see your reply... Yes, I will try to simplify my project and get a small one for your check. Working on it now.

Comment: Cool thanks! I totally couldn't make your code produce any issue. It worked perfectly. So something else is going on.

Comment: Well, this is the test project `https://github.com/Haibo-Zhou/DependencyInjTest`. And, I found the issue after a bit of debug. The reason is each TabViewController is embed in a NavigationController then my iteration in TabBarController actually access the one of navigation controller which is wrong.  I didn't mention it in my post, so you cannot repeat it, my bad. I try `if let vc = naviController.viewControllers[0] as? SongsViewController` to access deeper to my SongsViewController and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the solution code in case anyone may meet this after, it may save your precious time.

Basically say the 1st level we got is the navigationControllers, then we should go deeper to find that child view in navigationController. In my case, the 1st child of navigationController is the VC I want to access `naviController.viewControllers[0]`.

`TabBarController -> NavigationControllers -> subViewControllers`

So change the code per your scenario.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var modelController: ModelController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else {
            return
        }
        
        if let naviController = viewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController {
            if let vc = naviController.viewControllers[0] as? SongsViewController {
                vc.modelController = modelController
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```